# Javascript (ES6) asynchronous callback execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

When many async functions have been queued up, will their callbacks execute sequentially or concurrently?

Comment: does [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) help? - specifically the ["Run-to-completion"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Run-to-completion) section, which I believe addresses your question almost directly

Comment: This video explains the answer to your question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Not sure why this question was tagged with ES6. The parallelism of (function) execution is a property of the runtime environment and has nothing to do with the language version.

Comment: ES6 is just the JS version I'm using. If the behaviour was up to the run time environment it would be chaos!? V8 vs spider monkey vs whatever. all doing different things--I don't think so. Doesn't the language spec specify the final behaviour irrespective of particular engine implementation?? (I'm not a JS developer so don't know if 'thread' management if different over past versions that's why I specified ES6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They are run sequentially**, even though they may be queued up in an asynchronous manner.

Events are triggered in a multi-threaded area of the browser called Web APIs. Following an event (e.g. XHR request) being triggered *asynchronously*, an event loop *synchronously* selects the event's callback onto JavaScript’s **single-threaded call stack** to be executed.

[Dan Martensen offers a nice detailed writeup on the subject](https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/events-concurrency-and-javascript/)